# how to randomize a Facebook friend in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, random

I am trying to randomize a Facebook friend from my firend list.

since I am very new to PHP, can someone assist me and let me know how to do so?

```
$friends_json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$session["access_token"]);
$friends = json_decode($friends_json, true);
$friend_rand = array_rand($friends, 1); // <-- is that right? how can I print it on screen?
```

Comment: You are aware that it's `/me/friends` and not `/mefriends`, right? I've fixed it for you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

array_rand returns an array of keys. Since you're extracting only one element the code to print is

```
echo($friend_rand[0]);
```

Andrea's answer works as well, but that will print the array (not the element).

Answer (score 1):

Randomizing the entire array of friends is a waste of code and processing, simply to pull one random name from the array.

Just select a random key from the array.  Instead of your last line, use:

```
echo $friends[mt_rand(0, count($friends)-1)];
```

Comment: note that mt_rand is faster and produces a more random result set.

Comment: Huh - so it is.  You'd wonder why they left rand() in, if it's both slower and less random - especially since the interfaces are identical.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your code is *almost* right, the issue is the returned result is wrapped in the "data" array, so you need to do this:

```
$friends_json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$session["access_token"]);
$friends = json_decode($friends_json, true);
$k = array_rand($friends["data"]);
echo $friends["data"][$k]["name"];
```

Or the last two lines can be replaced by:

```
echo $friends["data"][array_rand($friends["data"])]["name"];
```